# Which is a more efficient method, using a list comprehension or django's 'values_list' function?

Tags: django, python-3.x, performance

When attempting to return a list of values from django objects, will performance be better using a list comprehension:

```
[x.value for x in Model.objects.all()]
```

or calling list() on django's `values_list` function:

```
list(Model.objects.values_list('value', flat=True))
```

and why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The most efficient way is to do the second approach (using `values_list()`). The reason for this is that this modifies the SQL query that is sent to the database to only select the values provided.

The first approach FIRST selects all values from the database, and after that filters them again. So you have already "spend" the resources to fetch all values with that approach.

You can compare the queries generated by wrapping your QuerySet with `str(queryset.query)` and it will return the actual SQL query that gets executed.

See example below

```
class Model(models.Model):
    foo = models.CharField()
    bar = models.CharField()

str(Model.objects.all().query)  
# SELECT "model"."id", "model"."foo", "model"."bar" FROM "model"

str(Model.objects.values_list("foo").query)
# SELECT "model"."foo" FROM "model"
```

Comment: What about using `.only("id")` in the first scenario? Then the two queries are identical.

Answer (score 2):

I had also somewhat assumed the argument in the currently-accepted answer would be correct. Namely, having a fewer number of fields being fetched would lead to `Model.objects.all()` taking less time than `Model.objects.values_list('foo')` to execute. However, I didn't find this in practice when using `%timeit`.

I actually found that doing 
`Model.objects.values_list('foo', flat=True)` would take ~2-10x longer than just `Model.objects.all()`. I found this was the case for

- an empty django table
- a table with 10s of rows
- a table with millions of rows

Including/removing flat=True seemed to make no significant difference in executing time for values_list. I would be interested what others find as well?

So this makes me think from a pure "what SQL is executed" point of view, although the values_list ORM query fetches fewer field values from the db, I imagine there is more logic still within the source django code of `.all()` vs `.values_list()` which could lead to different additional execution times (including `.all()` taking *less* time).

However, to fully address the initial example code, we would also need to factor in any further considerations affecting the execution time due to using a list comprehension `[]` in the `.all()` case VS `list()` in the `.values_list()` case. The general discussion of `list()` VS a list comprehension is covered in other questions already.

TLDR So I imagine it is a trade-off between those 2 factors.

1. the apparent difference in execution time between `.values_list()` and `.all()` (which from my tests indicate we can't simply deduce fewer fields being fetched leads to faster execution - more investigation of underlying django source code needed for cause of this)
2. any differences between using a list comprehension and `list()`

In my test cases, I generally found the `.all()` query was actually faster than the `.values_list()` query, but when also factoring in the transformation to a list, the `.values_list` scenario would overall take less time. So it may well depend on the scenario...

Comment: I'm finding, like you, that `values_list()` often increases the time over `objects.all()` in a list comprehension.

Comment: I find this a little of an odd argument. I rarely, if ever use .all() to make a list, but instead use filter() with values_list(). since filtering and obtaining values both occur in the database with such a call, the performance of such a call would depend on your filtering parameters, and your DB's set-up. I would suggest using aggregates or raw sql rather than doing a .all() list comprehension. These again remove processing from the slower orm to internally in the DB